# Prevent URL value from being cut off while passing to conrtroller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-controller, urlmappings.groovy

I think the issue is with the UrlMapping file or some configuration file that I don't know about but I didn't see it addressed [in this site](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) so I'm posting for help.

I have a UrlMappings.groovy with:

```
"/lookupMap/$fromVal/$toVal/xml/$id**" (controller:"lookup, action:"returnMapXml", formats=['xml'], method:"GET")
```

and the controller is:

```
def returnMapXml = {
  if (params.id) {
    print  params.id + "\n";
    try {
      def result = getLookup.result(params.fromVal, params.toVal, params.id)
      render ...yadda yadda
    }
  }
}
```

This is a REST service. My problem happens when someone enters an ID value with either a pound sign (#) or question mark (?), the value is truncated at that character. For example the output of ID (per the print line in the code) for this:
 **localhost:8080/productdefinition/lookupMap/Denver/Toronto/carton OR container OR box? OR bag** 
would be 
**carton OR container OR box**
 It removes the ? and everything after it. This happens somewhere either before it gets to the UrlMappings file or when that directs the call to the controller. Either way, how can I stop this and where, which file do I fix this in? I don't have access to the server so I can't alter any URL encodings; this has to be a code update. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue isn't with Grails. It's actually a configuration issue with your container (Tomcat?). You need to configure it to allow those values in the URI. Typically they aren't allowed because they are used to indicate parameters on a GET URL or a ref to a link within a given page.

Comment: Or, your clients should encode their URLs properly. This isn't necessarily your problem to fix

Comment: @tim_yates Obviously that would be the best solution! +1

Comment: We are using Tomcat, I give that a look. The pound and question marks are wild card operators being used for their searches so they are allowed.

Comment: So if I was using binary, I could send it to you on a URL without encoding it? `?` and `#` have meaning in URLs. If you don't mean what they signify, then encode the URL client side before calling your rest service